# Уровень определения css

Tags: css

Создал класс для таблицы:

```
div.pageedit table {
    width:600px; 
    font-size: 14pt; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

В итоге, ко всем таблицам в диве применяется этот класс. Как сделать, чтобы он не применялся к вложенным таблицам?

```
<div class="pageedit">
  <table>
    <tr><td> таблица1 </td></tr>
    </table>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><td> таблица2 </td></tr>
      <tr><td>

        <table>
          <tr><td> таблица3 </td></tr>
        </table>

      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. в примере, чтобы работал только для "таблица1" и "таблица2"

[ссылка на пример в jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sBKRc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот так

```
div.pageedit > table {
width:600px; 
font-size: 14pt; 
margin: auto;}
```